# How to add programmatically List Widgets to TabBar?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-asynctask, futuretask

I am building an application that connects and sends requests to an HTTP server and when gets the responses parses them into a JSON Object and displays the output.
The problem occurs when i use the following method:

```
Future<List<Widget>> getPizzas() async {
    List<Widget> pizzasElements;
    await PizzeriaAPI().getMenu().then((response) {
      Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
      var pizzas = list.map((model) => Pizza.fromJson(model)).toList();
      pizzasElements =new List<Widget>.generate(pizzas.length, (int index){
        Row row = new Row();
        row.children.add(new Text(pizzas[index].name));
        row.children.add(new Text("${pizzas[index].price} \$"));
        row.children.add(new MaterialButton(color: Colors.green,child: Text("Add"),onPressed: (){
          // esegui il post
        }));
        return row;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getPizzas().then((List<Widget> response){
      return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
          ),
          home: DefaultTabController(length: 4, child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Pizzeria'),
              bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "Buy"),
                    Tab(text: "Orders"),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
                  ]
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: [
              Column(
                children: response,
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Orders")
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.settings)
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ]),
          )
          )
      );
    }
    );
  }
}
```

I obtain a Future Object and not a List Object.
The code used to display the elements is:

```
Column(
      children: response,
),
```

How can i obtain List from this method and display the output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getPizzas()` is async, meaning it returns a `Future`. What you require essentially means you should instead change your rendering code to this:

```
Column(
  children: pizzasElements,
),
```

Since you seem to be setting `pizzaElements` to contain your widget list.

## UPDATE:

What you need to do is to separate the build method from the request. So in your build function, simply call the `getPizzas()` function and forget about it. Like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getPizzas();
    return MaterialApp(...
```

Next, you need to make sure `pizzaElements` is initialized and is a class property instead of a local variable. So that would mean you'd need to be using a `StatefulWidget` and this would be happening in the State class.

```
List<Widget> pizzaElements = <Widget>[];
```

Then in `getPizzas()`, you need to make sure you call `setState` in order to have your widgets re-render with the list:

```
void getPizzas() {
  PizzeriaAPI().getMenu().then((response) {
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    var pizzas = list.map((model) => Pizza.fromJson(model)).toList();
    setState(() {
      pizzasElements = new List<Widget>.generate(pizzas.length, (int index) {
        Row row = new Row();
        row.children.add(new Text(pizzas[index].name));
        row.children.add(new Text("${pizzas[index].price} \$"));
        row.children.add(new MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text("Add"),
            onPressed: () {
              // esegui il post
            }));
        return row;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem remains the same because how can i set synchronously pizzasElements with the method getPizzas() in the build method?

Comment: I see. Editing my answer.